# Are both designs (see details) are correct to represent "not allowed" / ban?

Tags: logo, typography, icon, design-principles, favicon

I need this icon to design something (in typography).

Now, I just noticed it today... at some places this icon has +45 angle of the *diameter* and at some places it has -45, as show in the image:

[image]

Is only one of them is correct?

**OR** there is a specific rule like: To represent something is banned or not allowed, you can use a circle and a tilted line on it, irrespective of the angle?

Also, can we alter the width of the tilted diameter line? Or it should be same as the width of circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe there is a "correct" angle for the divider.

However most, if not all, governmental or "official" agencies will use the -45° angle on signage.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't wait before I could find an existing answer on other platforms. You may want to see this thread. They also mentioned same government thing. https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/1721

Comment: Would you please share your views about the edit I just did?

Comment: In fact there are not only ISO standards around the use of the interdictory circle, there are UK and US highway signage standards and a host of others... herein I link (intentionally) a Wikipedia article on this topic as it has a wealth of good solid data there as well as more referential links for further perusal: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol]

Comment: Well, a government, just like a corporation, will have "standards and practices" which designs must adhere to. If you are working for such an agency, you should be able to find such documentation as it relates to your work. If you *aren't* working for a company/government with standards, you can really make up your own if alterations fit your work in a more aesthetically pleasing manner. Knowing standards set by common agencies is *always* helpful, if for no other reason, to be aware of what viewers commonly associate with the symbol.

Comment: My point being... -45° and Pantone 187 may be a government standard. However, if -55° and Pantone 204 fits *your work* better, there is nothing preventing you from making that alteration in general.

Comment: And a good solid point it is!

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94409/discussion-with-scott @Scott